# How to upgrade PHP Alpine in Docker Container

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-passport

Basically, i have laravel version 8 and passport version 10 for authentication.
i have a problem when i try to install passport inside nginx terminal.
`php artisan passport:install`

The Error Said my php version was 7.3.26 while Passport needs php 7.4

Here is my Dockerfile looks like :

```
FROM composer:2 as vendor

COPY . .

RUN composer install \
    --ignore-platform-reqs \
    --no-interaction \
    --no-plugins \
    --no-progress \
    --no-dev \
    --no-scripts \
    --prefer-dist \
    && find /app -type d -exec chmod -R 555 {} ; \
    && find /app -type f -exec chmod -R 444 {} ; \
    && find /app/storage -type d -exec chmod -R 755 {} ; \
    && find /app/storage -type f -exec chmod -R 644 {} ;

RUN composer dump-autoload

FROM existenz/webstack:7.4-codecasts

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

COPY --from=vendor --chown=php:nginx /app /www

# https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/240
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing gnu-libiconv
ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so php

RUN apk -U --no-cache add \
    php7 php7-zip php7-json php7-openssl php7-curl \
    php7-zlib php7-xml php7-phar php7-intl php7-dom php7-xmlreader php7-xmlwriter php7-ctype \
    php7-mbstring php7-gd php7-session php7-pdo php7-pdo_mysql php7-tokenizer php7-posix \
    php7-fileinfo php7-opcache php7-cli php7-mcrypt php7-pcntl php7-iconv php7-simplexml
```

How can i upgrade my php version to 7.4, or maybe the worst case i have to downgrade laravel and passport version.

Comment: The bits at the bottom are pointing to a generic php7 version. You should be able to search for php 7.4 specific ones.

Comment: Do not use composer as your base image... rather install composer in top of a PHP image. Or even better, have two containers, one for PHP and another one to run composer

Comment: @DaronSpence i already tried to add specifically with php7.4, but when i build it , its show error like : the file is not found.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it using this commands:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add --update --no-cache libgd libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev freetype-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php.ini
```

Or you can follow this [article](https://dev.to/jackmiras/laravel-with-php7-4-in-an-alpine-container-3jk6)